# Is it possible to merge coverage reports from Trace32?

Tags: trace

Trace32 doesn't support to merge coverage reports from multiple executable binaries. One of them is like this:

[image]

To do this mission, the third parties normally have to develop such a tool that Trace32 should support but not.

[image]

For **OnChip Trace**, specific target dependence is unavoidable, such as: compiler, specific architect...

Does anyone know some third-party tool able to merge coverages that are generated by Trace32? I knew gcov/lcov can do that but it didn't support my Tasking compiler. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigating throughout some documents provided by Lauterbach GmbH, then the Trace-based Code Coverage uses an address-based tagging. It meant that the assembled test runs have to be performed on the same executable.

[image]

Therefore, to judge coverage rate of the whole project. Typically, third parties will develop a merge tool (look like GNU gcov/lcov) in order to summarize the total coverage rate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm work with T32 Lauterbach, about items of Call and Function Coverage.
In collabtoration with Lauterbach, we have implementated this feature (not yet available for all microcontroller) but already available from last T32 version.

Now it's possible to perform the incremental coverage from different ELF file.
For more deatails ask to me or technical support of Luaterbach.

Comment: Hello @GSferra. Can you provide more details of the coverage merging feature? I'm using the 2023.11 nightly, but I cannot find any mention in the docs of merging across different executables.